# Remove disabled class when response code is 1 in each element javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to remove class when get response back from my php script.
My php is script working fine, i'm getting response when there are multiple element as an array.
like this..

```
[{code: 0, message: "Please fill valid date of birth."}, {code: 1, message: ""}]
```

With my javascript i'm trying to check the condition when there is code:1 in every element remove the disabled class, when there is any code:0 do not remove the disabled class.

**Here is my JS**

```
//GET JSON from Validation.php and extract the nodes
  var response = xmlhttp.responseText;
  var parseJson = JSON.parse(response);
  var resultCode = parseJson.code;
  var resultMessage = parseJson.message;
  console.log(parseJson);
  parseJson.map(response => {

   //Style the button

     var element = document.getElementById('step');
        if(response.code == 0)
        {
          element.classList.add("disabled");
        }

        if(response.code == 1)
        {
          element.classList.remove("disabled");
        }
     });
```

Which is working fine only for one element when there are more element.
How can i loop here my if(response.code) for each element? Which check in every object if code is 1 remove class else remain enable.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you need to loop over all the elements and check. Easiest way would be to use some.

```
element.classList.toggle("disabled", parseJson.some(resp => !resp.code))
```

Comment: How can i use this with exist function above?

Comment: One more question related to this, i also have error message on each element when code is 0 should show error message.
This is the code i was using in the same function 
//Show Validation Message
   var items = document.getElementsByClassName("stepbirthVal"),i, len;
    for (i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
      items[i].innerHTML = response.message;
    }
How can i loop it with this?

Comment: Is it possible here to check more condition with this, like if response is 1 and other input type checked is.. How can i achieve this? Can you please help me... Thanks in advance.